# CiviCRM + Joomla Auto Sync

Tags: joomla, synchronization, civicrm

is there any way to automatically sync users from joomla and civicrm.

Im new from both. so maybe someone could help me with this. hanks

Comment: Show us your code, explain the attempts you made: which tables have you tried to sync, where did the errors occur?

Comment: CiviCRM has that built in. All users are contacts, not all contacts are users but there are configuration and profile options that let you create users for new contacts. If you haven't read the free CiviCRM eBook I definitely recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

As people log in, they'll automatically have corresponding contacts found or created in CiviCRM.  If you want to jumpstart the process, go in the Administer menu to Users and Permissions > Synchronize Users to Contacts.  That will find or create a contact for each Joomla user.

CiviCRM expects to have a contact for each Joomla user.  However, there's no expectation that each contact should have a corresponding user.  For many organizations, only staff have user accounts.